# What is operator "?."?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I have been in a conference and speaker's example has '?.' operator.
What is it?

Similar code:

```
var result = man?.Name;
```

Comment: already this question is answered at SO.please make a research before asking a question

Comment: This is indeed not valid, it might be, You typoed it or someone else. Look for this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx   - damn, C#6 ? Ok, will remember that.

Comment: @utility I've tried really, but google and stackoverflow find nothing :-(
It's very complicated to find something with two symbols '?.'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's c# 6.0 syntax, Null propagation Operator. It means :

```
var p = man;

if(p != null)
{
   var result = man.Name;
}
else
{
   var result = null;
}
```

More info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx

Comment: This isn't completely correct.  If `man` is `null` then `result` will be set to `null` as well, which your example does not really show.

Comment: @Milen It's good article about c# 6.0, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

It is called [Null-propagating operator](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/900017/Null-Propagation-Operator-A-New-Feature-of-Csharp) in C#-6.0 version.

```
var result = man?.Name;
```

is equal to

```
var temp = man;
var result = (temp != null) ? man.Name : null;
```

- [The New and Improved C# 6.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx)
- [Null-propagating operator `?.`](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/540883)
- [Null-propagating operator details](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/540281)

Comment: Wow, I can't tell you how many times I've wished for that type of thing.